# Strange persistent resource served from localhost on Mac

Tags: reactjs, macos, react-router, frontend, create-react-app

I'm totally lost on this one.  I have a React app running locally (create-react-app) and a specific route is trying to serve old content (from another project which no longer exists on my machine) on a page refresh (programatic routing via reach/router renders the page fine). This behavior does not occur on my colleagues machines...

So for example https://localhost:3000/test/stuff serves some weird old content upon direct navigation (via browser) but not on programatic routing (via reach/router).  If I change the routing in the app to https://localhost:3000/DIFFtest/stuff the page renders correctly.

This occurs on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.  I have cleared all my browsers cache, and emptied the contents of `~/Library/Caches` on my mac.  Still this issue persists.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what else I could try to remedy this?

Comment: I'm interested to see what the actual problem is, hope someone will answer. But in the meantime you could try use a different port,  and have you tried restarting your machine?

Comment: I did try restarting my machine and that didn't resolve it, but I do NOT see this behavior on other ports.  I can totally work around this but I'm really curious to understand why it is happening...